# Will calling AJAX in constant interval burden the server and browser itself?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently developing a website where notification is needed. Therefore, I would like to call AJAX and detect changes on my database (storing notifications) constantly in a certain interval.

So my question is, as there are many users calling the AJAX at a `same time` and at `constant rate`, will performing such task **burden the server**?

And will this **burden the browser** for each users? I had a little bit of `performance issues` (slow loading / lag) when testing the website when I enable this method.

If this method is bad, can I have some *suggestion* for alternative method for this task?

Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: Have you considered using a `websocket` instead?

Comment: @Mike I am now doing some researches on it. I am kinda new on this area(web development). Thanks for the suggestion =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recurrent Ajax call your server will have to handle all those connections so yes it will load.

Another approach you can look is using websocket. Your client will subscribe to a chanel and your server ONLY when a change will be detected in database, will send a notification to the client.

With websocket your server push notifications to the client instead of a client fetching the notification.

Comment: does a websocket support notification like the one on Facebook, Twitter, etc.? I mean the normal notification but not the push notification.

Comment: Push notification isn't in websocket. You can see websocket like IRC chat for instance so it looks to be what you need

Comment: great! One last and dumb question, `IF` just if I insist to use AJAX, is there any way for me to minimize the burden of the server?

Comment: Reduce the number of calls by decreasing the frequency. Also put the result of your request in cache for X minutes in redis/memcache

Comment: Thanks sir. You helped a lot.